# In Chrome, after submitting a form and navigating back, its values are autofilled after DOMContentLoaded. Is it possible to listen for this change?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

See an example here: https://large-platinum-ethernet.glitch.me.

Using Google Chrome (using v81 as of May 2020):

1. Open your console.
2. Select a value other than "Option 0."
3. Click "Submit."
4. Press "Back" in your browser.
5. The value of the select element will be updated to the value of the select when you submitted the form. If you check the console, though, you'll see the value is "Option 0" initially, and it is updated to the value prior to navigation some time between `DOMContentLoaded` and `window.onload`.

Does anybody know if it's possible to listen for when Chrome makes this change? No `change` or `input` event is fired. I've tried using a `setTimeout` inside the `DOMContentLoaded` handler, and that seems to work, but seems hacky and potentially inconsistent.

Edit: It looks like the short answer is "no, there isn't an event that's triggered when Chrome changes the values." It is possible instead to see if the page was loaded after a navigation event. If it was, any form values set by `window.onload` can be assumed to have been set by the browser.

Comment: look up bfcache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like pageshow is buggy.

`performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward`

(Deprecated value) `window.performance.navigation.type === 2`

You can also use `autocomplete=off` on your form inputs

EDIT: pageshow doesn't work as of 5/6/2020 on Chrome 81
pageshow/pagehide events to detect loading from bfcache, which is where the form values are loaded from.

https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Websites/webkit.org/blog-files/pageshow-pagehide-example.html
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/page-lifecycle-api
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageshow_event

```
function pageShown(evt)
{
    if (evt.persisted)
        ; // do things to your forms
    else
        ; // no need to do anything
}

function pageHidden(evt)
{
    if (evt.persisted)
        ; // do things to your forms
    else
        ; // no need to do anything
}

window.addEventListener("pageshow", pageShown, false);
window.addEventListener("pagehide", pageHidden, false);
```

Comment: It looks like by the time `pageshow` is fired, the form values have already been set. So, the persisted property is always returning false. I've updated my original example to a include `pageshow` event listener.

Comment: updated the answer with a value you can check to see if it's being loaded from bfcache

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Looks like performance.navigation.type is deprecated, and PerformanceNavigationTiming.type (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigationTiming/type) should be used instead. Thanks for pointing me in that direction, though!

Comment: Chromium bug report for pageshow persisted property: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=344507.

Comment: [Chrome 79 not reflecting DOM state in onpageshow after back navigation](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1035662) might also be of interest.